# FabricJS - Create group of objects including custom extended object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric JS to draw on a canvas. I've created a custom object called LineArrow which extends the `fabric.Line` object and adds an arrow to the end. Here is the basic code and a JSFiddle of it working https://jsfiddle.net/oyqw228o/9/

```
const LineArrow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
  type: 'line-arrow',

  initialize(element, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    this.callSuper('initialize', element, options);

    // Set default options
    this.set({
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true,
    });
  },

  _render(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

    // do not render if width/height are zeros or object is not visible
    if (this.width === 0 || this.height === 0 || !this.visible) return;
    ctx.save();

    const xDiff = this.x2 - this.x1;
    const yDiff = this.y2 - this.y1;
    const angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
    ctx.translate((this.x2 - this.x1) / 2, (this.y2 - this.y1) / 2);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Move 5px in front of line to start the arrow so it does not have the square line end showing in front (0,0)
    ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, 5);
    ctx.lineTo(-5, -5);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.stroke;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  },
});
```

This renders as expected, however what I want to do is to add 'anchor points' to the start and end of this object to allow people to alter the line. The anchor points should only display if the line is selected. This is how I'd like it to look:

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle trying to render a group consisting of the custom line and 2 basic fabric.Circle objects https://jsfiddle.net/6v0s0h1x/3/

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: o.setCoords is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two circle and add to canvas. When you select a line object you need to make the circle visible using `visible = true`.
And set left and top of circles from selected line points(x1,y1,x2,y2).

On moving of circle you need to get the points from left/top and set to selected line points.

On selected line deselect disable the circles .

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/oyqw228o/10/).